# Unity Facebook SDK authenticate with right appid but wrong display application

Tags: ios, facebook, unity-game-engine

We've been through a weird issue today with the Facebook Unity SDK on iOS platform.

The problem occurs when we try to login, the app asks permissions, but the application name, and link, are from another app we created months ago.
When we delete the Facebook application, it loads the login page on safari, and in the URL parameters, we can see the AppId from the other app !

Everything is correctly setup into the FacebookSettings, the AppId is the right one, and when we launch the InteractiveConsole test scene, the Init button gave us aswell the feedback with the right AppId.

We tried this on Android platform, and it works just fine.
We also tried on different devices, to delete the facebook app on the devices, to re create a new app on the facebook developers, and finally, to build from another mac into a clean device. Nothing seems to help.

Has anyone any leads on this issue ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found out the problem came from the Prime 31 plugin - even if we didn't use the specific facebook plugin, as we used other plugins, the facebook entry was overwritten into the plist files on the postprocess.

Thanks anyway.